# Given set of points, how to generate polyhedron in Javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, polyhedra

I am doing a WEBGL visualization project in material science. What I am trying to accomplish right now is that, I have a set of 3D coordinates of atoms. They are bonded together. I would like to create a polyhedron for each molecule.

I noticed that in [Matlab there is a handy function called `alphaShape` which can determine the most similar shape according to your input points and return the best match of polyhedron.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html)

I tried to solve the problem by using brute force method: I traverse the whole point array and form triangles with every combination of three points. The following problem with that is then how can I detect which faces to get rid of? Cuz some of the triangle faces will go through the center atoms that the peripheral atoms are bonded with.

I will appreciate any suggestion and idea! 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you trying Googling ["alpha shape JavaScript"](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=alpha+shape+javascript)?

Comment: @gman Of course I did, but the first several results I got was all about 2D points alpha shape. I am looking for a 3D solution like alpha shape in Matlab lol.

Comment: Huh, the first hit for me says "any dimensional"

Comment: @gman Yeah it says any dimensional but the demo clearly demonstrate it only works in 2D. I check the source code. Changing the alpha doesn't change anything with the dimension. :(

Comment: It doesn't clearly demonstrate it only works in 2d. Just because the example is 2d doesn't mean it doesn't support 3d. I suck at math so I have no idea if it's working for the given parameters but here's the results of giving it 3d points

https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/L16jkzbs/

Comment: Looks to me that the alpha parameter doesnt relate to the dimension-ness but relates to the tolerance to concavity.

Comment: @gman Wow, thanks for the demo! It really helps! Do you wanna make that an answer so that I can endorse you for someone who might has the same problem in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a library [alpha-shape](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/alpha-shape) that seems to do what you want.

I gave it a set of sphere points and let it generate the triangles.

Example:

```js
//var alphaShape = require('alpha-shape')

var subdivisionsHeight = 12;
var subdivisionsAxis = 16;
var longRange = Math.PI * 2;
var latRange = Math.PI;
var radius = 4;

var points = [];
for (var y = 0; y <= subdivisionsHeight; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < subdivisionsAxis; x++) {
    // Generate a vertex based on its spherical coordinates
    var u = x / subdivisionsAxis;
    var v = y / subdivisionsHeight;
    var theta = longRange * u;
    var phi = latRange * v;
    var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
    var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
    var cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
    var ux = cosTheta * sinPhi;
    var uy = cosPhi;
    var uz = sinTheta * sinPhi;
    points.push([radius * ux, radius * uy, radius * uz]);
    if (y == 0 || y == subdivisionsHeight) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

// var cells = alphaShape(0.1, points)
// Results from alphaShape

var cells = [ [ 2, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3 ],
  [ 0, 3, 4 ],
  [ 5, 0, 4 ],
  [ 5, 6, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6 ],
  [ 0, 7, 8 ],
  [ 0, 16, 1 ],
  [ 9, 0, 8 ],
  [ 0, 9, 10 ],
  [ 0, 10, 11 ],
  [ 1, 18, 2 ],
  [ 0, 11, 12 ],
  [ 18, 3, 2 ],
  [ 0, 12, 13 ],
  [ 14, 0, 13 ],
  [ 3, 20, 4 ],
  [ 0, 14, 15 ],
  [ 4, 20, 5 ],
  [ 15, 16, 0 ],
  [ 5, 22, 6 ],
  [ 22, 7, 6 ],
  [ 18, 1, 17 ],
  [ 24, 8, 7 ],
  [ 19, 3, 18 ],
  [ 9, 8, 24 ],
  [ 19, 20, 3 ],
  [ 9, 26, 10 ],
  [ 20, 21, 5 ],
  [ 10, 26, 11 ],
  [ 22, 5, 21 ],
  [ 1, 16, 32 ],
  [ 1, 32, 17 ],
  [ 11, 28, 12 ],
  [ 22, 23, 7 ],
  [ 13, 12, 28 ],
  [ 23, 24, 7 ],
  [ 14, 13, 30 ],
  [ 25, 9, 24 ],
  [ 15, 14, 30 ],
  [ 25, 26, 9 ],
  [ 16, 15, 32 ],
  [ 26, 27, 11 ],
  [ 28, 11, 27 ],
  [ 18, 17, 33 ],
  [ 29, 13, 28 ],
  [ 13, 29, 30 ],
  [ 35, 19, 18 ],
  [ 20, 19, 35 ],
  [ 15, 30, 31 ],
  [ 15, 31, 32 ],
  [ 21, 20, 37 ],
  [ 37, 22, 21 ],
  [ 23, 22, 39 ],
  [ 18, 33, 34 ],
  [ 23, 39, 24 ],
  [ 34, 35, 18 ],
  [ 24, 41, 25 ],
  [ 20, 35, 36 ],
  [ 20, 36, 37 ],
  [ 26, 25, 42 ],
  [ 27, 26, 43 ],
  [ 17, 32, 48 ],
  [ 22, 37, 38 ],
  [ 17, 48, 33 ],
  [ 22, 38, 39 ],
  [ 44, 28, 27 ],
  [ 29, 28, 44 ],
  [ 40, 24, 39 ],
  [ 29, 45, 30 ],
  [ 24, 40, 41 ],
  [ 41, 42, 25 ],
  [ 31, 30, 47 ],
  [ 32, 31, 47 ],
  [ 26, 42, 43 ],
  [ 43, 44, 27 ],
  [ 50, 34, 33 ],
  [ 45, 29, 44 ],
  [ 34, 51, 35 ],
  [ 30, 45, 46 ],
  [ 35, 51, 36 ],
  [ 30, 46, 47 ],
  [ 36, 52, 37 ],
  [ 48, 32, 47 ],
  [ 37, 54, 38 ],
  [ 33, 48, 49 ],
  [ 50, 33, 49 ],
  [ 38, 55, 39 ],
  [ 55, 40, 39 ],
  [ 34, 50, 51 ],
  [ 41, 40, 56 ],
  [ 51, 52, 36 ],
  [ 57, 42, 41 ],
  [ 52, 53, 37 ],
  [ 58, 43, 42 ],
  [ 54, 37, 53 ],
  [ 59, 44, 43 ],
  [ 54, 55, 38 ],
  [ 45, 44, 61 ],
  [ 56, 40, 55 ],
  [ 46, 45, 62 ],
  [ 56, 57, 41 ],
  [ 62, 47, 46 ],
  [ 58, 42, 57 ],
  [ 63, 48, 47 ],
  [ 58, 59, 43 ],
  [ 48, 64, 49 ],
  [ 59, 60, 44 ],
  [ 60, 61, 44 ],
  [ 50, 49, 66 ],
  [ 66, 51, 50 ],
  [ 45, 61, 62 ],
  [ 52, 51, 68 ],
  [ 47, 62, 63 ],
  [ 53, 52, 68 ],
  [ 63, 64, 48 ],
  [ 70, 54, 53 ],
  [ 70, 55, 54 ],
  [ 65, 66, 49 ],
  [ 72, 56, 55 ],
  [ 51, 66, 67 ],
  [ 57, 56, 72 ],
  [ 68, 51, 67 ],
  [ 74, 58, 57 ],
  [ 69, 53, 68 ],
  [ 69, 70, 53 ],
  [ 59, 58, 75 ],
  [ 64, 80, 49 ],
  [ 65, 49, 80 ],
  [ 59, 76, 60 ],
  [ 70, 71, 55 ],
  [ 61, 60, 76 ],
  [ 71, 72, 55 ],
  [ 61, 78, 62 ],
  [ 73, 57, 72 ],
  [ 73, 74, 57 ],
  [ 63, 62, 79 ],
  [ 58, 74, 75 ],
  [ 80, 64, 63 ],
  [ 76, 59, 75 ],
  [ 66, 65, 81 ],
  [ 77, 61, 76 ],
  [ 67, 66, 82 ],
  [ 78, 61, 77 ],
  [ 62, 78, 79 ],
  [ 84, 68, 67 ],
  [ 80, 63, 79 ],
  [ 85, 69, 68 ],
  [ 70, 69, 85 ],
  [ 65, 80, 81 ],
  [ 70, 86, 71 ],
  [ 82, 66, 81 ],
  [ 87, 72, 71 ],
  [ 83, 67, 82 ],
  [ 83, 84, 67 ],
  [ 72, 89, 73 ],
  [ 89, 74, 73 ],
  [ 85, 68, 84 ],
  [ 74, 90, 75 ],
  [ 86, 70, 85 ],
  [ 76, 75, 92 ],
  [ 86, 87, 71 ],
  [ 93, 77, 76 ],
  [ 72, 87, 88 ],
  [ 77, 93, 78 ],
  [ 72, 88, 89 ],
  [ 78, 94, 79 ],
  [ 89, 90, 74 ],
  [ 79, 96, 80 ],
  [ 90, 91, 75 ],
  [ 80, 96, 81 ],
  [ 75, 91, 92 ],
  [ 76, 92, 93 ],
  [ 98, 82, 81 ],
  [ 83, 82, 99 ],
  [ 93, 94, 78 ],
  [ 99, 84, 83 ],
  [ 95, 79, 94 ],
  [ 100, 85, 84 ],
  [ 96, 79, 95 ],
  [ 102, 86, 85 ],
  [ 97, 98, 81 ],
  [ 103, 87, 86 ],
  [ 88, 87, 103 ],
  [ 99, 82, 98 ],
  [ 88, 104, 89 ],
  [ 84, 99, 100 ],
  [ 89, 106, 90 ],
  [ 100, 101, 85 ],
  [ 101, 102, 85 ],
  [ 107, 91, 90 ],
  [ 96, 112, 81 ],
  [ 112, 97, 81 ],
  [ 92, 91, 107 ],
  [ 102, 103, 86 ],
  [ 92, 108, 93 ],
  [ 104, 88, 103 ],
  [ 94, 93, 110 ],
  [ 89, 104, 105 ],
  [ 105, 106, 89 ],
  [ 94, 111, 95 ],
  [ 111, 96, 95 ],
  [ 106, 107, 90 ],
  [ 108, 92, 107 ],
  [ 98, 97, 113 ],
  [ 108, 109, 93 ],
  [ 114, 99, 98 ],
  [ 93, 109, 110 ],
  [ 94, 110, 111 ],
  [ 100, 99, 116 ],
  [ 101, 100, 117 ],
  [ 96, 111, 112 ],
  [ 101, 117, 102 ],
  [ 97, 112, 113 ],
  [ 102, 118, 103 ],
  [ 98, 113, 114 ],
  [ 120, 104, 103 ],
  [ 114, 115, 99 ],
  [ 116, 99, 115 ],
  [ 105, 104, 121 ],
  [ 100, 116, 117 ],
  [ 106, 105, 122 ],
  [ 107, 106, 122 ],
  [ 117, 118, 102 ],
  [ 124, 108, 107 ],
  [ 118, 119, 103 ],
  [ 119, 120, 103 ],
  [ 109, 108, 125 ],
  [ 110, 109, 125 ],
  [ 104, 120, 121 ],
  [ 105, 121, 122 ],
  [ 110, 127, 111 ],
  [ 111, 127, 112 ],
  [ 107, 122, 123 ],
  [ 128, 113, 112 ],
  [ 123, 124, 107 ],
  [ 129, 114, 113 ],
  [ 125, 108, 124 ],
  [ 114, 131, 115 ],
  [ 110, 125, 126 ],
  [ 115, 131, 116 ],
  [ 127, 110, 126 ],
  [ 117, 116, 133 ],
  [ 127, 128, 112 ],
  [ 118, 117, 133 ],
  [ 118, 135, 119 ],
  [ 114, 129, 130 ],
  [ 120, 119, 135 ],
  [ 114, 130, 131 ],
  [ 137, 121, 120 ],
  [ 132, 116, 131 ],
  [ 122, 121, 137 ],
  [ 116, 132, 133 ],
  [ 139, 123, 122 ],
  [ 128, 144, 113 ],
  [ 133, 134, 118 ],
  [ 144, 129, 113 ],
  [ 135, 118, 134 ],
  [ 140, 124, 123 ],
  [ 125, 124, 140 ],
  [ 136, 120, 135 ],
  [ 125, 141, 126 ],
  [ 120, 136, 137 ],
  [ 142, 127, 126 ],
  [ 138, 122, 137 ],
  [ 138, 139, 122 ],
  [ 128, 127, 144 ],
  [ 139, 140, 123 ],
  [ 146, 130, 129 ],
  [ 141, 125, 140 ],
  [ 130, 146, 131 ],
  [ 141, 142, 126 ],
  [ 148, 132, 131 ],
  [ 127, 142, 143 ],
  [ 127, 143, 144 ],
  [ 133, 132, 149 ],
  [ 149, 134, 133 ],
  [ 145, 129, 144 ],
  [ 150, 135, 134 ],
  [ 145, 146, 129 ],
  [ 152, 136, 135 ],
  [ 131, 146, 147 ],
  [ 147, 148, 131 ],
  [ 136, 153, 137 ],
  [ 138, 137, 153 ],
  [ 132, 148, 149 ],
  [ 139, 138, 155 ],
  [ 134, 149, 150 ],
  [ 140, 139, 155 ],
  [ 151, 135, 150 ],
  [ 152, 135, 151 ],
  [ 141, 140, 157 ],
  [ 152, 153, 136 ],
  [ 141, 158, 142 ],
  [ 142, 158, 143 ],
  [ 138, 153, 154 ],
  [ 159, 144, 143 ],
  [ 138, 154, 155 ],
  [ 160, 145, 144 ],
  [ 156, 140, 155 ],
  [ 140, 156, 157 ],
  [ 145, 162, 146 ],
  [ 141, 157, 158 ],
  [ 163, 147, 146 ],
  [ 163, 148, 147 ],
  [ 158, 159, 143 ],
  [ 164, 149, 148 ],
  [ 159, 160, 144 ],
  [ 149, 166, 150 ],
  [ 162, 145, 161 ],
  [ 151, 150, 167 ],
  [ 152, 151, 167 ],
  [ 162, 163, 146 ],
  [ 152, 168, 153 ],
  [ 163, 164, 148 ],
  [ 154, 153, 170 ],
  [ 165, 149, 164 ],
  [ 166, 149, 165 ],
  [ 155, 154, 171 ],
  [ 145, 160, 176 ],
  [ 161, 145, 176 ],
  [ 156, 155, 171 ],
  [ 150, 166, 167 ],
  [ 156, 172, 157 ],
  [ 168, 152, 167 ],
  [ 158, 157, 174 ],
  [ 153, 168, 169 ],
  [ 153, 169, 170 ],
  [ 175, 159, 158 ],
  [ 160, 159, 175 ],
  [ 154, 170, 171 ],
  [ 172, 156, 171 ],
  [ 161, 177, 162 ],
  [ 172, 173, 157 ],
  [ 177, 163, 162 ],
  [ 157, 173, 174 ],
  [ 164, 163, 177 ],
  [ 177, 165, 164 ],
  [ 175, 158, 174 ],
  [ 177, 166, 165 ],
  [ 167, 166, 177 ],
  [ 176, 160, 175 ],
  [ 168, 167, 177 ],
  [ 177, 161, 176 ],
  [ 169, 168, 177 ],
  [ 169, 177, 170 ],
  [ 170, 177, 171 ],
  [ 171, 177, 172 ],
  [ 172, 177, 173 ],
  [ 174, 173, 177 ],
  [ 175, 174, 177 ],
  [ 175, 177, 176 ] ]

function flatten(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }, []);
}

// the cells are triangle (3 points). To draw lines we need 6 A->B, B->C, C->A
function expandToLines(cells) {
  return flatten(cells.map(function(cell) {
    return [cell[0], cell[1], cell[1], cell[2], cell[2], cell[0]];
  }));
}

var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;
var fs = `
precision mediump float;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var arrays = {
  position: flatten(points),
  indices: expandToLines(cells),
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  var projection = m4.perspective(
      60 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 20);
  var eye = [1, 4, -10];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  var view = m4.inverse(camera);
  var viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  var world = m4.rotateX(m4.rotationY(time), time * 0.7);

  var uniforms = {
    u_matrix: m4.multiply(viewProjection, world),
  };

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.LINES);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Note that you need to make sure you don't give it any coincident points. Notice the sphere point generation avoids making coincident points.

Comment: Cool! I will try to implement it right now. Thanks! :)